# How can I create data-driven text inputs with Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to create several inputs that update my Ember Data model immediately, without a submit action.  E.g.

```
Person
First Name  [Placeholder: Enter first name ]
Last Name   [Placeholder: Enter last name  ]
City        [Placeholder: Enter city       ]
```

I’ve approached this by creating a wrapper component around an Ember TextField subclass component, and have gotten it to work, kind of, but with two major problems:

1. Placeholders don't work as I tried to implement them (see below) — seems I could do this a lot more easily using the TextSupport mixin, but I don't know how to use it.
2. I don't like the way I am sending change actions up to the route, which is basically like this:

Within a top-level component `{{person-view action="modifyPersonInternals"}}` I have my wrapper components as follows:

```
{{editable-property property="firstName" action="updateFirstName"}}
{{editable-property property="lastName" action="updateLastName"}}
{{editable-property property="city" action="updateCity"}}
```

When the user edits the `firstName`, the TextField component calls `updateFirstName` on the `editable-property` wrapper component with a parameter (the new value); the wrapper component in turn calls `modifyPersonInternals` on the route with two parameters (the property to modify, and the new value).  This works but seems clunky/hacky and can't be the right approach, can it?

Also, here's my unsuccessful attempt to implement a placeholder in `editable-property.js`,

```
hasEmptyProperty: Ember.computed(function() {
    return ((this.get('property') === "") || (this.get('property') === null));
})
```

and in editable-property.hbs:

```
{{#if hasEmptyProperty}}
<div class="placeholder" {{action "editProperty"}}>{{placeholder}}</div>
{{else}}
<div {{action "editProperty"}}>{{bufferedProperty}}</div>
{{/if}}
```

I get an error that `hasEmptyProperty` is not defined.

Comment: I may be missing something, but why does `{{input value=model.firstName placeholder="Enter first name"}}` not work?

Comment: If you are going to do this, then I think `hasEmptyProperty` needs to be  `return this.get('model').get(this.get('property')) === "" || this.get('model').get(this.get('property')) === null;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing the model into the component anyway, why not just directly associate the models property with your input?

`{{input value=model.firstName}}`

This will achieve your goal, but if you are trying not to pass the model into the component then the best way is to send an action as you are doing.

With regard to the `hasEmptyProperty` I would instead have a property called `hasEmptyProperty` and a function that sets it, something like...

```
checkEmptyProperty: function() {
  var property = this.get('property');
  if(property === "" || property === null ) {
    this.set('hasEmptyProperty', true);
  } else {
    this.set('hasEmptyProperty', false);
}.observes('property'),
```

Comment: This ALMOST works — if the property changes, hasEmptyProperty updates correctly.  But it doesn't evaluate initially, defaulting to false for each property, even where the property actually is empty.

Comment: Works if I use `.on('didInsertElement').observes('property')`

Comment: I init everything seperately. So will usually have:

    setup: function() {}